# Uncaught Type Error on Invisible reCaptcha while Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to implement new invisible recaptcha by google.

But i have required inputs and should validate the form before recaptcha execute.

I got an error on recaptcha callback function like that:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById() submit is not a function

So how can i submit the form after validate and recaptcha executed?

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<form id="form" action="?" method="post">
     Name: (required) <input id="field" name="field">
     <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey="6LcAmBAUAAAAAFukLQIkOIICuBBxKEdn-Gu83mcH"
          data-callback="onSubmit"
          data-size="invisible"></div>
     <button id='submit'>submit</button>
   </form>
<script>onload();</script>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
  alert('Thanks ' + document.getElementById('field').value + '!');
  document.getElementById('form').submit(); // This is error line
}

function validate(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!document.getElementById('field').value) {
    alert("Please enter your name.");
  } else {
    grecaptcha.execute();
  }
}

function onload() {
  var element = document.getElementById('submit');
  element.onclick = validate;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dp1cLh28/6/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.

Issue is button id named as `submit` (`button id="submit"`) conflicting with `.submit()` function.

When i change the button id, it works!

**Change the button id**:

```
<button id='action'>Submit</button>
            ^ submit > action or whatever
```

Answer (score 5):

## Check your domain whitelist

I had this error and could not solve it until I found out the error was that I simply had not added the correct domain to the domain whitelist.

The domain error does not appear on the console and I had not noticed the tab that displays the error on the page (below):

[image: Invalid domain name for site key]

Comment: Thank you! This was the case for me as well. If you are debugging locally using 127.0.0.1 or something similar that has not been added to the list of allowed domains, this is likely the cause.

Comment: Thank you. In my case missed GOOGLE_RE_CAPTCHA_KEY
was undefined from config!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an input (type="submit") tag in the form instead of a button.  The name of the input was conflicting with the submit function.

The solution was to give the input tag a name different from "submit":

```
<input type="submit" name="anything-except-submit">
```

I had to name the tag explicitly, because the name was defaulting to "submit" from the type attribute.

It is also important to note that the callback will only be called when the user successfully solves the reCAPTCHA, so if your callback is doing any form validation you must call

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```

if the validation fails.  That means that the user will have to solve the reCAPTCHA again, but otherwise he would not be able to submit the form after making corrections.