# Uncaught (in promise) null anchor

Tags: invisible-recaptcha

I have the same error "**Uncaught (in promise) null [anchor](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Lcvw3oUAAAAABOL_UvTNZidZn4L9NqJ57rkPjIl&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9saXByb3RlY3QtbGl2ZS5jb206NDQz&hl=en&v=v1541614764654&size=invisible&badge=inline&cb=77v8vqsszgkf)**" and can not submit for with "onSubmit". I using [proggramatic execute](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute). I already used in more then 10 form and today I has issue on two of 5 forms.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google reCaptcha response "Uncaught (in promise) null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390562/google-recaptcha-response-uncaught-in-promise-null)

Answer (score 4):

I found solution, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860168/uncaught-type-error-on-invisible-recaptcha-while-form-submit). So, if Submit button is type submit and name is submit, you prevent form from sending and then you want to trigger with .submit() form that cause error on my captcha.

Comment: No. It doesn't help in ionic